# What is the timezone_type property of DateTime object?

Tags: php, json, datetime

I wonder what this output of `echo json_encode(new \DateTime());` means:

```
    {
        "date":"2019-04-16 14:43:15.126710",
        "timezone_type":3,
        "timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"
    }
```

`date` and `timezone` are obvious... but what is this `timezone_type`? The official documentation didn't help me much. The page about [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) speaks of no such thing, it just mentions you can get/set a DateTimeZone. The page about [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) doesn't help either.

So... what is it? Where does PHP get it from? And what is it good for?

Comment: That question asks how to construct DateTimes in a particular way. This question asks what a particular property of DateTime is. I think they are related, but not duplicate.